# losing session variable on popup

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am losing the data stored in the session variable when I try to open the popup from the hyperlink. Below is my code

```
   <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%#"~/Viewer/DetailsViewer.aspx?ID=" + Eval("Id") + "&QueryID=" + Request.QueryString["QueryID"]%>'
                                                Text="View" />
```

The session variable in the code above gets cleared out in IE. The version that I am using is 8.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using cookieless sessions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if IE8 holds session in new windows. To test, try opening the hyperlink in the same window (take out `target="_blank"`). Either way, I'd suggest either storing it in a cookie or passing it with the querystring if it isn't sensitive data.